# Blank Product Export - please help!

Tags: import, products

We have had no success in exporting our 100k+ product list using Magento's standard export.  The export keeps timing out and we get a blank screen.  We have tried upping the memory allocation and also tried going to data profiles for all products to set the file to run in popup and save on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase max_execution_time in .htaccess.

Also try to set php_value memory_limit 512M.

It worked for me on Magento 1.7